# Chef-solo: Missing Cookboks for Run List

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook, berksfile

I want to start deploying components with `chef-solo`.
I've also configured the `solo.rb` and `node.json` .

Whenever I run the command: `chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json`
I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
Could not satisfy version constraints for: build-essential

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* blueprint-yum::default
* coremedia::chef_logging
* coremedia::reporting
* mysql::server
* coremedia::db_schemas
* mongodb::default
* coremedia::solr_master
* coremedia::master_live_server
* coremedia::content_management_server
* coremedia::workflow_server
* coremedia::caefeeder_preview
* coremedia::caefeeder_live
* coremedia::studio
* coremedia::studio_apache
* coremedia::certificate_generator
* coremedia::delivery
* coremedia::delivery_apache



Running handlers:
[2018-04-06T12:39:45+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2018-04-06T12:39:45+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
[2018-04-06T12:39:45+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef-solo/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2018-04-06T12:39:45+02:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2018-04-06T12:39:45+02:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"
[2018-04-06T12:39:45+02:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

node.json:

```
{
  "fqdn":"bender",
  "mysql":{
    "allow_remote_root":true,
    "bind_address":"xxx.x.x.x",
    "use_upstart":false,
    "server_repl_password":"xxx",
    "server_debian_password":"xxx",
    "server_root_password":"xxx",
    "tunable":{
      "wait_timeout":"7200"
    },
    "client": {
      "packages": ["mysql-community-client", "mysql-community-devel"]
    },
    "server": {
      "packages": ["mysql-community-server"]
    }
  },
  "coremedia":{
    "db":{
      "schemas":["cm7management",
                 "cm7master",
                 "cm7replication",
                 "cm7caefeeder",
                 "cm7mcaefeeder"]
    },
    "yum":{
      "local": {
        "path": "/opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/target/shared/rpm-repo/",
        "archive": "/opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/target/shared/rpm-repo/"
      }
    },
    "content_archive_url":"/opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/target/shared/content/content-users.zip",
    "content_archive":"/opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/target/shared/content/content-users.zip",

    "configuration":{
      "configure.STUDIO_TLD":"bender",
      "configure.DELIVERY_TLD":"bender",
      "configure.CROWD_APP_NAME":"admin",
      "configure.CROWD_PASSWORD":"x",
      "configure.CROWD_SERVER":"Crowd Server:8443",
      "configure.ELASTIC_MAIL_HOST":"webserver@testhh.de",
      "configure.DELIVERY_REPOSITORY_HTTP_PORT":"42080",
      "configure.DELIVERY_SOLR_PORT":"44080"
    },
    "logging":{
      "default":{
        "com.coremedia":{"level":"info"},
        "cap.server":{"level":"info"},
        "hox.corem.server":{"level":"info"},
        "workflow.server":{"level":"info"}
      }
    },
    "tomcat":{
      "manager":{
        "credentials":{
          "admin":{
            "username":"admin",
            "password" : "x",
            "roles"    : "manager-gui"
          },
 "script": {
            "username" :"script",
            "password" : "x",
            "roles"    : "manager-jmx,manager-script"
          }
    }
      }
    }
  },
  "run_list":[
  "recipe[blueprint-yum::default]",
  "recipe[coremedia::chef_logging]",
  "recipe[coremedia::reporting]",
  "recipe[mysql::server]",
  "recipe[coremedia::db_schemas]",
  "recipe[mongodb::default]",
  "recipe[coremedia::solr_master]",
  "recipe[coremedia::master_live_server]",
  "recipe[coremedia::content_management_server]",
  "recipe[coremedia::workflow_server]",
  "recipe[coremedia::caefeeder_preview]",
  "recipe[coremedia::caefeeder_live]",
  "recipe[coremedia::studio]",
  "recipe[coremedia::studio_apache]",
  "recipe[coremedia::certificate_generator]",
  "recipe[coremedia::delivery]",
  "recipe[coremedia::delivery_apache]"
  ]
}
```

solo.rb:

```
file_cache_path '/var/chef-solo/cache'
cookbook_path ['/opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks', '/opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/chef/chef-repo/berks-cookbooks']
role_path ['/var/chef-solo/roles', '/opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/chef/chef-repo/roles']
data_bag_path '/var/chef-solo/data_bags'
```

Content of my metadata.json (cookbook: build-essential):

```
{
  "name": "build-essential",
  "description": "Installs C compiler / build tools",
  "long_description": "",
  "maintainer": "Opscode, Inc.",
  "maintainer_email": "cookbooks@opscode.com",
  "license": "Apache 2.0",
  "platforms": {
    "amazon": ">= 0.0.0",
    "centos": ">= 0.0.0",
    "debian": ">= 0.0.0",
    "fedora": ">= 0.0.0",
    "freebsd": ">= 0.0.0",
    "mac_os_x": ">= 0.0.0",
    "mac_os_x_server": ">= 0.0.0",
    "oracle": ">= 0.0.0",
    "redhat": ">= 0.0.0",
    "scientific": ">= 0.0.0",
    "smartos": ">= 0.0.0",
    "suse": ">= 0.0.0",
    "ubuntu": ">= 0.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "recommendations": {
  },
  "suggestions": {
    "pkgutil": ">= 0.0.0"
  },
  "conflicting": {
  },
  "providing": {
  },
  "replacing": {
  },
  "attributes": {
  },
  "groupings": {
  },
  "recipes": {
    "build-essential": "Installs packages required for compiling C software from source."
  },
  "version": "2.1.2"
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

**Update: chef-stacktrace.out:**

```
Net::HTTPServerException: 412 "Precondition Failed"
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http/response.rb:122:in `error!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/http.rb:152:in `request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/http.rb:131:in `post'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:177:in `sync_cookbooks'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:83:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/client.rb:513:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/client.rb:281:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application.rb:292:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application.rb:280:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application.rb:280:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application.rb:245:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application.rb:233:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application/client.rb:469:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application/client.rb:458:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application/client.rb:457:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application/client.rb:457:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application/client.rb:441:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:225:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:59:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:59:in `<main>'
```

**Berksfile**

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'


cookbook 'mongodb', '= 0.16.2'
# fixing the compat_resource cookbook that provides a compatibility layer for older chef versions and their concepts.
# here it provides mainly the compatibility layer for the old LWRP dsl which has been replaced in 12.5
cookbook 'compat_resource', '~> 12.10.7'

# vendored workspace cookbooks
cookbook 'coremedia', path: 'cookbooks/coremedia'
cookbook 'psdash', path: 'cookbooks/psdash'
cookbook 'blueprint-yum', path: 'cookbooks/blueprint-yum'
```

Comment: Any chance to see /var/chef-solo/cache/chef-stacktrace.out? build-essential 2.1.2 is quite old.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SzymonSzypulski Please see my updated question with the attached chef-stacktrace.out. Does it help to update the version on the `metadata.json` or the `metadata.rb` of the build-essential cookbook?

Comment: How can I update a cookbook?

Comment: I am not sure if the version is at fault. I see you have `berks-cookbooks` in cookbook directories list. Berkshelf should take care of all dependencies - so this should not happen. Have you changed something by hand, uploaded cookbook outside of berkshelf?

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski Not that I know of. But it won't change anything if I just remove the path of `berks-cookbooks` in the cookbook directories list right? How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Chef dependencies error are kinda tricky, at least from my experience. You could try to pull/update all dependencies with `berks update && berks vendor /opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/chef/chef-repo/berks-cookbooks`. Or even without `berks update`. Just keep in mind, it can break everything, so make a copy of your repo ;-)

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski Okay so I've run `berks vendor /opt/git/cm8-hamburg-de/boxes/chef/chef-repo/berks-cookbooks` and even after executing `berks update` (which worked properly) I'm getting the same error message . So the issue could be because of the old version **build-essential 2.1.2** right?

Comment: Could be. You can bump it in Berksfile do update/vendor 'dance'. But if any cookbook is in an incompatible version Berkshelf should fail.

Comment: I think there is something missing on my `Berksfile` . Could you please take a look at it @SzymonSzypulski ? Please see my updated question. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I would say it is at least outdated or incomplete. I do not think there is a easy way to help you, without access to the code.